# The header & footer php call for html site is not working

Tags: php, html, css

my header.php and footer.php files are not getting fetched by the index.html file. I've searched through Stackoverflow and have followed different variations such as `<?php include("header.php"); ?>` or `$("#header").load("header.html");` but it still doesn't work. My code as below, can someone advice me what I'm doing wrong?

Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>aaaa</title>
    <meta name="description" content="aaaa.">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='myfavicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

<header>
      <!-- HEADER -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img alt="aaaa" src="images/aa.png" height="30px">
        </a>
        </div>     
      </div><!--END CONTAINER FLUID-->
    </nav>
```

Index.html

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row feature">
                <img src="images/Homepage%20Banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="aaaa">
                <div class="feature-text col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3">
                    <p>aaaaa</p>
                </div><!--END FEATURE TXT-->
            </div><!--END ROW FEATURES-->
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing in console? Is `header.php` in the same location as index is located? Change `index.html` to `index.php`. And, it is not `$("#header").load("header.html");`, it should be `$("#header").load("header.php");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of index.html change index.php.
by using php file only we can include other php file.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code lies in the files with extension `.php`.
And in `Header.php`, if you have no php code, then just write them in `.HTML` extension i.e. `Header.html`
So, rename the `index.html` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to.

Here `<?php  include("header.php") ?>` is php code in HTML File.

You need to change the index.html to index.php